# Regular Expression, words with different characters

Tags: regex, chars

I have been searching about it for about 3 hrs, now I'm stuck.
Here is the problem:

I want to find 7 character word where **only** 4. and 6. chars are same

like:

```
^...(.).\1.$
```

but i don't want to find

```
aaaBaBa
```

all other chars must different than each other like:

```
asdBfBg
```

my question is similar to this one: [Java: Regular expression where each character occurs 0-1 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933119/java-regular-expression-where-each-character-occurs-0-1-times)

but my knowledge wasn't enough to work with **Lookarounds** (?<= and (?=, (?

Comment: Could you give some more sample strings for what you want your regex to match on, and what you don't want it to match on?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use a negative assertion, like this:

```
^(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)\4(.)(?<!(?:\1.*\1|\2.*\2|\3.*\3|\4.*\4.*\4|\5.*\5|\6.*\6).*)$
```

This will find any 7-letter word with the 4th and 6th letters the same, and whose 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 5th, or 7th (`\6`) letter do not appear twice, and whose 4th letter is not repeated three times.

Comment: Did you try this? It seems off and I don't know if many regex engines allow back-references in lookbehinds.

Comment: @pguardiario Yes, I tested it and it does work using the .NET engine.

Comment: I keep getting errors on visual regexp it gives me **"quantifier operand invalid"** and on bash with using grep it says **"Invalid back reference"**

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that works, maybe there's a better way to do this though.

```
/
\b # word boundary
(\w) # any word char
(?!\1)(\w) # any word char except \1
(?!\1|\2)(\w) # any word char except \1 or \2
(?!\1|\2|\3)(\w) # etc...
(?!\1|\2|\3|\4)(\w)
\4 # 4th capture
(?!\1|\2|\3|\4\5)(\w)
\b # word boundary
/x
```

Comment: did you try this because on grep i get **"Invalid back reference"**

Comment: This is a perl-style regex. I don't believe that grep is sophisticated enough for something like this.